# How to debug function file causing white screen

Tags: functions, fatal-error

My `function.php` file seems to be causing a white screen to appear whenever I try to login to the dashboard locally. I have confirmed this by renaming the 'function.php' file and also the plugins file to identify the problem area.

I'm pretty new to Wordpress and would like to know how to exactly pinpoint the line of code in the function.php file thats causing problems. Below is my code.

Prior to this I also noticed that my media library would not work. The spinner would simply spin and show none of my images

**function.php**

```
<?php

// Call Stylesheets
function wpSam_theme_styles(){

   wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.min.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpSam_theme_styles');


// Call Scripts
function wpSam_theme_js(){

// 1.name 2. 3. Directory 4. dependencies  5. 6. appear in footer (t/f)
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js' , '', '', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js' , '', '', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpSam_theme_js');


function time_ago( $type = 'post' ) {
$d = 'comment' == $type ? 'get_comment_time' : 'get_post_time';

return human_time_diff($d('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . " " . __('ago');

 }

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse239844_image_sizes' );

 function wpse239844_image_sizes() {
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 470, 295, true ); // $width, $height, $crop
 }


  add_action( 'post_stuck', 'wpse239911_only_one_sticky' );

  function wpse239911_only_one_sticky( $post_id ) {
remove_action( 'post_stuck', 'wpse239911_only_one_sticky' );
// prevent loop
delete_option( 'sticky_posts' );
stick_post( $post_id );
 }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a fatal error occurring, but you aren't displaying errors on the page.

To enable debugging you should add the following code to your wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

*note: if your wp-config.php file already contains an entry for the above, make sure it's set to true.

Once you know what is causing the error you can go about trying to fix it.

Comment: I already set it to true. I changed the file name to x-functions.php and got the dashboard up and running then changed the file name back to function.php and now my media library is not showing my media/images :/

Comment: Okay, you should check the error logs for your local Web server. Which webserver are you running?

Comment: I'm running MAMP and to my knowledge that runs an APACHE server.

Comment: Okay, go to your PHP Tab within MAMP and you should see the location of your php_error.log file. Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: Yeah I think i've found it but its still not very clear to me

Comment: Okay, refresh the web page you are having problems with and then open up your error log file. Paste the last 3 entries here so we can see the error details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46173/discussion-between-tguimond-and-samsos).

Comment: I've discovered the issue.. There was extra spacing at the end of the function.php file after the closing tag. Wordpress does not like this. I removed. Refreshed the page and images loaded again